# Count number of sentences containing same word count

Tags: python

I have the following question:

> Given a text, count the number of sentences sharing the same number of words. The result for:
>
> ```
> s = 'I am in grade 12. I want to go to Harvard.'
> ```
>
> should be `{5: 1, 6: 1}`.

Here is my attempt:

```
self.sentence_length = {}
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == '.':
        sentence = s[:i]
        l = len(sentence.split(' '))
        if l in self.sentence_lengths:
            self.sentence_lengths[l] += 1
        else:
            self.sentence_lengths[l] = 1
```

which gives me the (wrong) result `{5: 1, 11: 1}`.

Comment: Print out `sentence` after the line `sentence = s[:i]`

Comment: You are using sentance[:i] which means all words before current index, including previous sentences. I would suggest to split the first string into sentences by dot (.) and process them one by one

Answer (score 0):

First, define a generic function for counting the number of words in a sentence:

```
def word_count(sentence):
    return len(sentence.split(' '))
```

and another one for splitting a text into sentences:

```
def sentences_from(text):
    stripped = (s.strip() for s in text.split('.'))
    return [s for s in stripped if s]
```

Then (renaming your "`s`" with a clearer `text`) the mapping you need is a simple [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections

collections.Counter(word_count(s) for s in sentences_from(text))
```

Obviously, like your code, the previous functions miss **many** corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
from itertools import count

s = 'I am in grade 12. I want to go to Harvard.'
sentences = list(filter(None, s.split('.')))  # filter removes empty string
# sentences holds ['I am in grade 12', ' I want to go to Harvard']

>>> dict(zip(count(1), list(map(lambda x: len(x.split()), sentences))))
{1: 5, 2: 6} # first sentence has 5 words, second has 6 words
```

**Note:** Use the length of the sentence as the value of the dictionary, Because if more than one sentence has the same length then it will overwrite the dictionary.